# How do initialize iOS vecLib vU1024 data type?

Tags: ios, bignum

Using the iOS vecLib BigNum.h vU1024 data type, how should I go about initializing with some number?

For example, how do I get the big number 938429845792837192837293487293458734985791823123918237 in there?

Thanks.